# Does Nashorn Javascript compile "eval" statements?

Tags: javascript, jvm, jit, nashorn

I understand that Nashorn compiles to JVM byte code on the fly.  But, what does Nashorn do when it encounters the eval function with a String?  Does it compile the string contents or interpret it?

For example:

```
function sayHi() {
  console.log("hi world");
}

for (var i=0;i<10;i++) {
   eval("sayHi()"); // what happens here?
}
```

A couple options could be:
1) it does not compile the string within an eval
2) it compiles it once, caches it, and then reuses the same byte code if it encounters the same string (as in the loop above)
3) it re-compiles the contents of an eval String a-fresh each time

Of course this is a small example in which the contents of an eval string is just a method call, but imagine it is more complex JS code being passed as a string into eval.

Comment: There's little point using `eval()` with a hardcoded string - not that `eval()` is recommended in general, but if you *are* going to use it the point is usually to pass it a dynamically created string with a value that isn't known at compile-time.

Comment: Ok, so let's assume that the string to eval is dynamic.  Is it then first compiled on the fly JIT into a temporary class, and then immediately class unloaded.  Or, is it just interpreted similar to Rhino interpreted mode? Or another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nashorn always compiles javascript to bytecode for execution. There is no interpreter for JS. Yes, compiled/loaded Classes are unloaded if not reachable from live objects.

Comment: So, in the above example, within the loop, each time the eval is called there is a fresh recompile/unload class, even if the eval has encountered the same string in the past?

Comment: No, there will be cache hit for the same code. i.e., won't be recompiled again. Depending on if alive cache is available, compilation is avoided. But, code will be run again definitely.

Comment: So, to avoid the recompile in the eval(String) does it check it against String.equals to see if that particular string has already been compiled.  Thanks for your expert help.

Comment: That's right - in case you're curious, the relevant Source and Class cache code is here -> http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/nashorn/file/8a875db19be8/src/jdk.scripting.nashorn/share/classes/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/Source.java & http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk9/dev/nashorn/file/8a875db19be8/src/jdk.scripting.nashorn/share/classes/jdk/nashorn/internal/runtime/Context.java

Comment: Does ScriptEngine.eval(Reader reader, ScriptContext ctxt) do something similar?  If the scriptEngine evals a reader with the same filename, does it avoid the IO and just use the cache, or does it do the IO, load the string, then check the cache?